# Which ATI driver version did 10.04 use?

Tags: drivers, ati

I have a trouble with ATI driver with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I install ATI driver in Ubuntu 12.04 via "Additional Driver", then I can't shutdown Ubuntu, it showed blank (black) screen and my laptop still run. Sometimes, my screen like that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9_iygesbBM

But when I install Ubuntu 10.04 and install ATI driver via "Additional Driver", it's very good and no trouble I've seen. It's sweet but 10.04 is old and is supported to 4/2013. So I want to know why Ubuntu 10.04 works good better than 12.04 with ATI driver (in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here with this answer, but it's the best I could figure out:

10.04 uses:

```
xserver-xorg-video-ati (1:6.13.0-1ubuntu5)
    X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
```

ref: [Lucid package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/allpackages)

12.04 uses:

```
xserver-xorg-video-ati (1:6.14.99~git20111219.aacbd629-0ubuntu2)
    X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
```

ref: [Precise package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/allpackages)

I'm not sure if this helps you at all since I'm not too sure how you would about getting the older version. Perhaps adding the Lucid repository in your apt sources file and installing it that way.